# Fast embedded database

Tags: c++, database, data-structures, embedded-database

I am working on an application which will need to store metadata associated with music files (artist, title, play count, etc.), as well as sets of integers (in particular, SHA-1 hashes).

The solution I pick needs to:

- Provide "fast" storage & retrieval (when viewing a list of potentially thousands of songs I need to be able to retrieve metadata more or less interactively).
- Be cross-platform (to Linux, Windows and OSX).
- Provide an interface I can interact with from C++.
- Be open-source (or, at the very least, be free as in beer).
- Provide fast set operations (union, intersection, difference) - if the solution doesn't provide this, but it will allow me to store binary data, I could implement this myself using a technique like ["Fast Set Operations Using Treaps"](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~scandal/treaps.html).
- Be "embedded" - that is, operate without me having to `fork` another process, or at least provide an easy interface to do so (like libmysqld).

Solutions I have considered include:

- Flat files. This is extremely simple, but doesn't provide any features besides flat data storage.
- SQlite. This seems to be a very popular option, but it seems to have some issues regarding performance and concurrency (see [KDE's Akonadi](https://techbase.kde.org/Projects/PIM/Akonadi/Database#Sqlite), for some example issues).
- Embedded MySQL/MariaDB. This seems to be a reasonable option, but it also might be a bit heavyweight considering I won't be needing a lot of complicated SQL features.

A hypothetical solution I'm thinking would be perfect would be something like Redis, but which persists data to the disk, and only stores some portion of the data in memory to make retrieval fast. Redis itself might not be a good option because 1) I would need to `fork` it manually, 2) its Windows port seems less than rock-solid, and 3) storing **all** of my data in RAM would be less than ideal.

Are there any other solutions for this type of problem, or is one of the solutions I have already listed far better than the others?

Comment: *Mutex-based transaction serialization in Akonadi (required because SQlite's support of concurrency might not be enough) can block clients while background operations such as a IMAP sync are going on.* Huh? Why the *heck* are people doing IMAP sync (whatever that means) while having a lock on their database, and calling in *an SQLite problem*?

Comment: You know, the benchmarks on SQlite's site seem to totally contradict what KDE has said about it, and Akonadi being awful wouldn't totally surprise me. Perhaps SQlite is indeed worth more investigation.

Comment: SQlite is used everywhere from your browser to production servers that can handle thousands of users (been there, done that, got the T-shirt). It is not a performance problem.

Comment: I don't understand why people are voting to close this question, when every single question over in the "Related" column is very similar and has not only not been closed, but has upvotes. Asking what type of database should be used for a specific problem seems to be in the category of "**software tools commonly used by programmers**" from the FAQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I've decided to use SQlite for metadata. It seems to be as fast if not faster than e.g. libmysqld, and it has a really simple clean C interface. According to benchmarks, it should be way more than fast enough to suit my needs.

For larger data structures, I'm planning on just storing them in separate binary files (the SQlite website says it can store binary data, but that if your data size exceeds a certain amount it is faster to store it in flat files instead - see [this page](http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html)).

Answer (score 3):

Don't store you binary files BLOBS inside SQLite, unless you want an elephant size database. Just store a string with the path file name on the file system. The only downside of SQLite is that it does not allow remote (web) access, but you can embedded it inside a small TCP/HTTP server.

Comment: this is an example of a small TCP server that can receive SQL queries encoded in a JSON array, and make calls to SQLite. 
https://github.com/pedro-vicente/lib_netsockets/blob/master/examples/sqlite_server.cc